# Performing a biserial correlation on SPSS v21

Tags: correlation, spss

I have a set of data in which the response variable is continuous and the other independent variables are dichotomous (not naturally occurring).

I think I have to perform Biserial correlation (I an aware of the difference between point biserial and biserial correlation).

How can I do this on SPSS or any other statistical software?

Comment: Please visit my web-page. In "Various proximities" you will find computation of biserial as well as point-biserial correlations.

Comment: If you have a dependent and an independent variable, then why not use regression?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for "Point-Biserial" correlation coefficient, just find the Pearson correlation coefficient. In SPSS, click Analyze -> Correlate -> Bivariate. The rest is pretty easy to follow. Computationally the point biserial correlation and the Pearson correlation are the same.

Comment: _Are you sure_ the biserial correlation was introduced in version 21?

Comment: I stand corrected. What I meant was the "Point-Bieserial" correlation coefficient.